# Machine learning layer to target features

Tags: deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm relatively new to machine learning and after a few days of browsing the internet on how it actually works, I have a few questions especially on how to target some features.

To the best of my understanding, a convolutional layer can extract features from the input image. The machine looks for the best kernel based on the activation and kernel size e.t.c. I.E. it learns the best kernel for that layer. Then it outputs the features for the next layer to take a look at.

However, what if I want to specifically target a feature? For example, I know that my two classifications of images will have vastly different average pixel intensity. How do I tell the CNN to look for the pixel intensity? And based on that, optimize the weight of the neuron?

Any help will be much appreciated, thank you for your time.

EDIT: Turns out I was deeply misinformed about machine learning. The answer below explains it very well and sorted out my confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mostly correct but I think your terminology is a bit off. The `conv` layer tries to learn the best kernel but *for the dataset it's trained on*. If you have 2 different dataset and the same `conv` layer, the kernels after the training would be different, each one 'best' for the data it was trained on.

Now, you cannot select the features explicitly like that. That is the beauty of neural networks. You have to let the NN figure out how will it represent the features and knowledge and which features it will select. What you can do is preprocess the dataset in a different way and/or adapt the kernel for the task. So, if the image has, let's say, more dense pixels, you can select the bigger kernel to cover the same area of the image in each step. Now, I don't know much about pixel intensities, but I'm sure that the NN would pick it up by itself, without your specific request. It's just the way you process the images before you input them into the NN. You should always standardize (average or normalize) the data in the training for maximum accuracy. Take a look in a concept of [batch normalization](https://towardsdatascience.com/batch-normalization-in-neural-networks-1ac91516821c)

Comment: Thank you I think I understand! Looks like my approach to try and extract specific features was incorrect. Thanks!